# What's the minimal largest eigenvalue of the sum of two symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $|\cdot|$ be the matrix spectral norm. That is, for an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix $A$,
$$
|A|=\max_{|x|=1}|Ax|
$$
where the norm $|Ax|$ is obviously the Euclidean norm of the vector $Ax$. Consider the norm of the matrix $SAS^{-1}-B$ where $A,B$ are real symmetric and $S$ is orthogonal (that is, $SS^T=I$ so that $SAS^{-1}$ is still symmetric.

The question is: what is the minimum value $|SAS^{-1}-B|$ can assume? Put otherwise, what is the maximum eigenvalue obtainable for $SAS^{-1}-B$ if we vary $S$ over all orthogonal matrices?

My intuition tells me that this minimum is achieved by aligning the eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$ and therefore when $A$ and $B$ are both diagonal but I'm quite stuck.

Comment: by perturbation theory, the norm $|SAS^{-1} - B|$ is at least the maximum of the ordered difference of their eigenvalues $\max_i |\lambda_i(A)-\lambda_i(B)|$ and you already found the $S$ that realizes the equality

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? For example, what result of perturbation theory? And I presume $\lambda_i(A)$ is the $i$th largest/smallest eigenvalue of $A$

Comment: Sorry, I just never touched perturbation theory.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality